# Change configuration during mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm just looking into the possibility of using AutoMapper in our application. Its working well however I have this situation. Given this class

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I can map to it fine using the default configuration

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Something, Foo>();
```

and then calling

```
.Project().To<Foo>();
```

(applied to an IQueryable)

However in one situation I don't want to map the Bar property through. I want it to be ignored. Is it possible to change the mapping configuration for this one time? If so how?

Comment: Will you be creating the map in a situation where you can do `if(I want Bar) CreateMapWithBar else (CreateMapWithoutBar)` or are you doing your create maps at startup?

Comment: I was hoping to create the maps at start up. Then choose to map the property based upon an if statement

Comment: Sorry then, I only know how to do it if you're creating the map as you need it.

Comment: Why not just skip that property after the mapping or set it too null after the mapping ?

Comment: @Tan thought about this however this is done as part of an EF query and isn't possible in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible, especially given you're using the EF way of mapping. You're really talking about conditional building of an expression tree. The best way to approach this problem is to create two separate destination types, perhaps using inheritance to add additional fields as necessary.

Comment: I was worried you were going to say that. This was my fall back plan. The situation is we need to make sure that certain customers don't get access to certain fields

Comment: You could create separate mapper instances, you don't have to use the static methods on `Mapper`. It can get complicated but you can create multiple instances of the mapping engine with their own configuration.